# Syntax error: end of file unexpected

Tags: shell, makefile, gnu-make

I define a function in Makefile

```
define write_file
for i in $( seq 1 10 )
do
    echo "1234567" >> "tmp/test.txt"
done
endef
```

And

```
pre:
    mkdir -p exe tmp
    ${call write_file}
```

But when I `make pre`,I got error:

> mkdir -p exe tmp
>   for i in 
>   /bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: end of file unexpected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each line of a make-recipe is a single command that `make` runs in a single
new shell. So you need to make the body of the macro `write_file` into a single
shell command.

In addition, `make` expands anything of the unescaped form `$(....)`,
treating `....` as a defined or undefined `make` expression. So in your
case, `make` expands `$( seq 1 10 )` to nothing. To stop `make` doing
that and let the shell expand `$( seq 1 10 )`, you need to escape `$` for `make`,
which you do by writing `$$` instead. The same goes for any `$` in a make-recipe
that you intend to be expanded by the shell.

Putting these points together, you want:

```
define write_file
for i in $$( seq 1 10 ); \
do \
    echo "1234567" >> "tmp/test.txt"; \
done
endef
```